# PhoneGap - contacts.create duplicates Contact in iOS

Tags: cordova, contacts

I am building an iOS Phonegap app that has the option to add info to a contacts entry using this JavaScript:

```
function saveContact() {
  var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
  contact.displayName = "Name";

  var phoneNumber = [];
  phoneNumber[0] = new ContactField('main', '5555555555', true);
  contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumber;

  var urlWeb = [];
  urlWeb[0] = new ContactField('home page', 'www.myurl.com', true);
  contact.urls = urlWeb;

  var streetAddress = [];
  streetAddress[0] = new ContactAddress('true', 'main', 'Full Address', '123 School St.', 'San Fransisco', 'CA', '00000', '');
  contact.addresses = streetAddress;

  var lastName = new ContactName();
  lastName.familyName = "Name";
  contact.name = lastName;

  var contactPhoto = [];
  contactPhoto[0] = new ContactField('photo', base64photo, false)
  contact.photos = contactPhoto;

  contact.note = contactNote;

  contact.save(contactSaveSuccess,contactSaveError);
}
```

When I execute this function once it works great and adds the contact. When I execute it a second time, it creates a second entry instead of updating it, as I understand it to do. I tried adding an ID using:

```
contact.id = 10000;
```

I event tried it with quotes:

```
contact.id = '10000';
```

...but that didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting rawId on contact object before save.
so do    contact.rawId = contact.id; 
and then try to save

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, I'm concatenating an id plus my orgname but feel free tu use your own fields like "firstname_lastname".toLowerCase();

```js
saveContact: function(event, idContact) {

    var name = $(".contactName"+idContact).text();
    var surname = $(".contactSurname"+idContact).text();
    var fonction = $(".contactFunction"+idContact).text();
    var email = $(".contactEmail"+idContact).text();
    var tel = $(".contactTel"+idContact).text();

    var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
    contact.id = idContact + "myorgname";
    contact.displayName = name;

    var contactName = new ContactName();
    contactName.givenName = surname;
    contactName.familyName = name;
    contact.name = contactName;

    var organizations = [];
    organizations[0] = new ContactOrganization(false, 'work', 'MyOrg','',fonction); // preferred
    contact.organizations = organizations;

    var emails = [];
    emails[0] = new ContactField('PhoneGap', email, true);
    contact.emails = emails;

    var phoneNumbers = [];
    phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('PhoneGap', tel, true);
    contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;

    contact.save(this.onContactSaved, this.onContactSavedError);
},
```